# How the computers can see my system over the web?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, virtualbox, port-forwarding

Actually I installed the Ubuntu in the VirtualBox on the Mac OS X 10.10, after that I start to listen the port 8080 on Ubuntu and then forward the port via virtualBox.

my modem is TP-Link, so I set the port forwarding to my client with local Ip address, 
with Nmap tool I search my public ip with another system in the internet with -Pn switch and it's shows the 8080 is open on this public ip.

with the other system on the internet I try to ping my public ip address but its shows "Request time out", so I go to my modem again and enable DMZ , now the ping is reply but when I put my ip address to the browser on the other systems on the web its say the server not found.

any idea?

Comment: did you specify 8080? even if you are in the DMZ, your host will only respond to forwarded ports. you could try a bridged connection in virtualbox, but that would open your ubuntu up a great deal, if you still have DMZ enabled. I would really disable DMZ. you don't need a webserver to respond to public ping.

Comment: is it related to static or dynamic ip address???

Comment: perhaps, but not if you can ping the public IP and get a response from the DMZ'd server. if you can, then your public IP has not changed. I'm assuming your VM has a static IP, or a dynamic one that "sticks" and does not change often. if you are concerned about that, statically configure the host and virtural guest.

Comment: Thanks Frank I tried to set VM as bridge but the virtual box didn't know wifi(air port)